# Como ordenar uma lista de tuplas pelo n-ésimo elemento?

Tags: python, tupla, classificação

Eu tenho uma lista de tuplas da forma:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, -5), (6, -3)]
```

Quero ordenar essa lista pelo segundo valor de cada tupla (isto é, no caso teríamos `[(4, -5), (6, -3), (0, 1), (2, 3)]`. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O jeito mais simples é usar `key` na chamada ao método `sort` da lista:

```
data = [(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, -5), (6, -3)]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

>>> data
[(4, -5), (6, -3), (0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Dessa forma, o elemento `1` de cada tupla será a chave de ordenação. Outra opção considerada [mais rápida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10695158/1071869) é utilizar a função `itemgetter` da biblioteca `operator`.