# Como posso ordenar uma lista pelo numero?

Tags: python

Olá, tenho esse pequeno sistema que pega o nome de 4 equipes e suas respectivas pontuações, guarda em uma lista e depois a ordena em ordem decrescente. Até aí tudo bem, mas o sistema está ordenando pelo nome das equipes em ordem alfabéica, eu queria que ao invés disso, ele ordenasse pelo valor da pontuação das equipes. Já procurei em vários lugares sobre como fazer e encontrei tutoriais confusos e não obtive resposta, se alguém pude ajudar eu ficaria grato!

```
data = []
for i in range(0,4):
    nome = str(input('Digite um nome: '))
    ponto = int(input('Digite a pontuação: '))
    dado = nome + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + str(ponto)
    data.append(dado)

data_sort = sorted(data, reverse=True)
print(data_sort)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está misturando as estruturas que utiliza para **armazenar** os dados da sua aplicação com as que utiliza para **exibí-los**. Exibição é só um detalhe, não deveria definir como você armazena os dados. No momento que você salva tudo como *string* para facilitar a exibição posterior você perde toda a consistência da sua informação e, por isso, terá grandes dificuldades em tratá-las depois.

**Solução:** saiba separar as coisas.

Armazene de uma forma que não perca a consistência e exiba depois da forma que desejar.

Por exemplo, se ao invés de você criar a *string* para armazenar a informação você definir uma tupla, onde o primeiro valor é a pontuação e a segunda é o nome da equipe, a informação se manterá consistente.

```py
data = [
  (20, 'Equipe 1'),
  (40, 'Equipe 2'),
  (15, 'Equipe 3')
]

data_sort = sorted(data, reverse=True)
print(data_sort)  # [(40, 'Equipe 2'), (20, 'Equipe 1'), (15, 'Equipe 3')]
```

Ao ordenar uma lista de tuplas, a ordenação ocorrerá primeiro pelo primeiro valor, que é a pontuação, e, em caso de empate, pelo segundo, que seria o nome da equipe, em ordem alfabética.

Comment: Certo, entendi. Mas a dúvida agora é como eu faria se quisesse ordenar pelo segundo valor da tupla como padrão, há alguma forma de fazer isso? Desculpe se a pergunta for um pouco burra, tenho bastante dificuldade nessa parte. =)

Comment: @RodrigoBorges https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/384/112052